# How to draw different coloured waves in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing

I want to know how to draw waves like patterns in photoshop easily.

I have attached an image of it so you can get an idea of what I'm talking about:

[image: waves]
<sub>(source: [gstatic.com](http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS3Aud4XUsEh_JDtmswHTWrVJxiIAlkC3q5dmpAbrbP2ikvyI6cPg))</sub>

Please anybody help me in this.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way. What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I didn't get stuck.I always draw it using pen tool

Answer (score 12):

Hard to say for sure from such a small image, but some of these look like they might be 3d.

---

The middle one on the right looks sort of like something that you could make with photoshop like this:

### 1.

Draw some random lines and or dots with the brush tool.

[image]

### 2.

From the top menu `Filter > Blur > Motion blur...`.
[image]

[image]

### 3.

Apply the blur couple more times ( ...or until it looks good... ).

<kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd + F</kbd> `x2`

[image]

### 3.123456789

It pays to experiment with stuff right about here, or after warping it. Stuff like adding sharpness or even blurring it some more.. Or adding extra brush strokes or something ( I didn't do anything extra here... ).

### 4.

- Activate Free transform: <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd+T</kbd>
- Right-click the document and select: Warp

[image]

### 5.

**Warp it like you mean it:**

[image]

and done! ...sort of... Of course you might want to continue by adding color, which you could do with Hue / saturation panel <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd+U</kbd> or something.

[image]

---

I made the image below by:

1. Making couple more of those
2. Inverting colors
3. Adding layer adjustment: Gradient map with soft light blend mode
4. Adding new layer on top of everything with overlay blend mode and brush some white in there with a soft round brush.
5. Adding another layer with bunch of colors brushed in and changing blend mode to overlay and opacity to about 30%

[image]

`I saved relatively good quality image incase anyone wants to use this image somewhere. Feel free to do what ever you wish to do with it.`